# Trying to print out a list of random IPs but keep encountering errors in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am not very experienced in Haskell so I am not too sure what's going on. I want to generate a list of random IP addresses and print them out but I keep encountering the errors below:

**My code:**

```
import System.Random (randomRIO)
import Data.List
import Control.Monad.Cont

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let maxtests = 5
    let mylist = createList maxtests []
    forM_ mylist $ \ip -> do
        print ip

createList :: Int -> [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
createList 0 mylist = return mylist
createList n mylist = do
    myarr <- randomIp 4
    let myip = (show (myarr !! 0)) ++ "." ++ (show (myarr !! 1)) ++ "." ++ (show (myarr !! 2)) ++ "." ++ (show (myarr !! 3))
    let mylist2 = mylist ++ [myip]
    let mylist3 = createList (n-1) mylist2
    return mylist3

randomIp :: Int -> IO([Int])
randomIp 0 = return []
randomIp n = do
    r  <- randomRIO (0,255)
    rs <- randomIp (n-1)
    return (r:rs)
```

**Error messages when I compile:**

```
test2.hs:13:23: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'
      Expected type: [[Char]]
        Actual type: [[[Char]]]
    * In the expression: return mylist
      In an equation for `createList':
          createList 0 mylist = return mylist
   |
13 | createList 0 mylist = return mylist
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

test2.hs:15:14: error:
    * Couldn't match type `IO' with `[]'
      Expected type: [[Int]]
        Actual type: IO [Int]
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: myarr <- randomIp 4
      In the expression:
        do myarr <- randomIp 4
           let myip
                 = (show (myarr !! 0))
                     ++
                       "."
                         ++
                           (show (myarr !! 1))
                             ++ "." ++ (show (myarr !! 2)) ++ "." ++ (show (myarr !! 3))
           let mylist2 = mylist ++ ...
           let mylist3 = createList (n - 1) mylist2
           ....
      In an equation for `createList':
          createList n mylist
            = do myarr <- randomIp 4
                 let myip = ...
                 let mylist2 = ...
                 ....
   |
15 |     myarr <- randomIp 4
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^

test2.hs:19:5: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'
      Expected type: [[Char]]
        Actual type: [[[Char]]]
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: return mylist3
      In the expression:
        do myarr <- randomIp 4
           let myip
                 = (show (myarr !! 0))
                     ++
                       "."
                         ++
                           (show (myarr !! 1))
                             ++ "." ++ (show (myarr !! 2)) ++ "." ++ (show (myarr !! 3))
           let mylist2 = mylist ++ ...
           let mylist3 = createList (n - 1) mylist2
           ....
      In an equation for `createList':
          createList n mylist
            = do myarr <- randomIp 4
                 let myip = ...
                 let mylist2 = ...
                 ....
   |
19 |     return mylist3
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Would appreciate any pointers on what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems all stem from not handling IO correctly.

First problem: `createList` calls `randomIP`, and `randomIP`'s result is in IO. Thus, `createList` must have its result in IO too. So change `createList :: Int -> [[Char]] -> [[Char]]` to `createList :: Int -> [[Char]] -> IO [[Char]]`.

Second problem: Since `createList`'s result is in IO, the recursive call to itself must unwrap the IO. So change `let mylist3 = createList (n-1) mylist2` to `mylist3 <- createList (n-1) mylist2`.

Third problem: Since `createList`'s result is in IO, `main`'s call to it must unwrap the IO. So change `let mylist = createList maxtests []` to `mylist <- createList maxtests []`.

With all of those changes, it compiles.

---

Bonus material below here:

Also, note that you've unnecessarily reimplemented a few functions that are already built in to Haskell: `replicateM`, `intercalate`, and `map`.

To make use of `intercalate` and `map`, change `let myip = (show (myarr !! 0)) ++ "." ++ (show (myarr !! 1)) ++ "." ++ (show (myarr !! 2)) ++ "." ++ (show (myarr !! 3))` to `let myip = intercalate "." (map show myarr)`.

Making use of `replicateM` requires much larger changes, so I'll just show you the result:

```
import System.Random (randomRIO)
import Data.List
import Control.Monad.Cont

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let maxtests = 5
    mylist <- createList maxtests
    forM_ mylist $ \ip -> do
        print ip

createList :: Int -> IO [[Char]]
createList n = replicateM n $ do
    myarr <- randomIp 4
    let myip = intercalate "." (map show myarr)
    return myip

randomIp :: Int -> IO [Int]
randomIp n = replicateM n $ do
    r  <- randomRIO (0,255)
    return r
```

You can even continue the refactoring further if you want, to something like this:

```
import System.Random (randomRIO)
import Control.Monad
import Data.Foldable
import Data.List

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let maxtests = 5
    mylist <- createList maxtests
    for_ mylist print

createList :: Int -> IO [[Char]]
createList n = replicateM n $ intercalate "." . map show <$> randomIp 4

randomIp :: Int -> IO [Int]
randomIp n = replicateM n $ randomRIO (0,255)
```

Comment: I believe that you meant `mylist <- createList maxtests []` for the third problem. Compiles and works fine now. Thanks!

Comment: @Vlam Yep, fixed now.

Comment: @Vlam Also, I edited in some extra tips, some of which you may find useful.

Comment: The code looks so simple and clean now. Thanks a lot!!